# Deploying Metadata to sandboxes using ant build

Tags: deployment, ant

We are using subversion to commit all our meta data changes from our sandboxes. When we deploy to a testing environment, we want to get only the changed meta data which we can get from svn and dynamically create a package.xml file which would only have the changed metadata components and folders. Does anybody have an ant script which creates a package.xml dynamically from subversion?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: Are you looking for windows script or unix based ?

Comment: @MohithKumar a windows script would work for us.

Comment: Sorry i love unix and fan of bash so windows script i dont have

Comment: @MohithKumar Someone could always use something like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run the bash scripts on windows, so if you have something bash specific it could still be useful.

Comment: @PeterKnolle posted the bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    #/usr/bin/env bash
# -bname build name
# -wspace build workspace dir
 # -lcommit builds last commit

#read command line args
while getopts b:w:l: option
 do
    case "${option}"
    in
            b) BNAME=${OPTARG};;
            w) WSPACE=${OPTARG};;
            l) LCOMMIT=${OPTARG};;
       esac
       done

echo Build Name: $BNAME
echo Workspace: $WSPACE
echo Last Commit: $LCOMMIT

#change working directory to the dir for this build
echo Changing working directory to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace

  # check for the existence of an existing commit file for this
  # project
  SCRIPTFILE='/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/lastcommit/'$BNAME'.txt'
  echo Searching for script file $SCRIPTFILE...
  if [ -e $SCRIPTFILE ]
   then
    PREVRSA=$(<$SCRIPTFILE) &&
    echo Found previous SHA $PREVRSA

    # Backup existing Package.xml
    cd $WSPACE/src
    echo changing directoy to $WSPACE
    cp package.xml{,.bak} &&
    echo Backing up package.xml to package.xml.bak &&
    read -d '' NEWPKGXML <<EOF
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Package>
   </Package>
 EOF      
    echo ===PKGXML===
    echo $NEWPKGXML
    echo Creating new package.xml
    echo $NEWPKGXML > $WSPACE/src/package.xml

    for CFILE in `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $LCOMMIT $PREVRSA`
    do
            echo Analyzing file `basename $CFILE`

            case "$CFILE"
            in
                    *.cls*) TYPENAME="ApexClass";;
                    *.page*) TYPENAME="ApexPage";;
                    *.component*) TYPENAME="ApexComponent";;
                    *.trigger*) TYPENAME="ApexTrigger";;
                    *.app*) TYPENAME="CustomApplication";;
                    *.labels*) TYPENAME="CustomLabels";;
                    *.object*) TYPENAME="CustomObject";;
                    *.tab*) TYPENAME="CustomTab";;
                    *.resource*) TYPENAME="StaticResource";;
                    *.workflow*) TYPENAME="Workflow";;
                    *.remoteSite*) TYPENAME="RemoteSiteSettings";;
                    *.pagelayout*) TYPENAME="Layout";;
                    *) TYPENAME="UNKNOWN TYPE";;
            esac

            if [[ "$TYPENAME" != "UNKNOWN TYPE" ]]
            then
                    ENTITY=$(basename "$CFILE")
                    ENTITY="${ENTITY%.*}"
                    echo ENTITY NAME: $ENTITY

                    if grep -Fq "$TYPENAME" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
                    then
                            echo Generating new member for $ENTITY
                            xmlstarlet ed -L -s "/Package/types[name='$TYPENAME']" -t elem -n members -v "$ENTITY" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
                    else
                            echo Generating new $TYPENAME type
                            xmlstarlet ed -L -s /Package -t elem -n types -v "" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
                            xmlstarlet ed -L -s '/Package/types[not(*)]' -t elem -n name -v "$TYPENAME" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
                            echo Generating new member for $ENTITY
                            xmlstarlet ed -L -s "/Package/types[name='$TYPENAME']" -t elem -n members -v "$ENTITY" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
                    fi
            else
                    echo ERROR: UNKNOWN FILE TYPE $CFILE
            fi
            echo ====UPDATED PACKAGE.XML====
            cat $WSPACE/src/package.xml
    done
    echo Saving last RSA Commit
    echo $LCOMMIT > /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/lastcommit/$BNAME.txt
    echo Cleaning up Package.xml
    xmlstarlet ed -L -s /Package -t elem -n version -v "27.0" $WSPACE/src/package.xml
    xmlstarlet ed -L -i /Package -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" $WSPACE/src/package.xml

    echo ====FINAL PACKAGE.XML=====
    cat $WSPACE/src/package.xml
 else
    echo No RSA found, default Package.xml will be used
    echo Creating new list commit file
    echo $LCOMMIT > /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/lastcommit/$BNAME.txt
fi
```

The above is the simple bash script that works .

Comment: Thx for the script. I will test this and let you know.